# Most efficient way to check if any element in a JSON array contains a specific id?

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, search

I am using Node v8.1.3

I have a JSON array as following:

```
[
  {
    "id":99,
    "name": "ABC"
  },
  {
    "id": 187,
    "name": "AXZ"
  }
]
```

This array has around **213000** e=objects in it.

Also, the `id`s in the objects are not in any order or pattern.

Now, I want to find if a particular `id` matches any ID in the array? what  is the fastest wait to do it?

I tried

```
isIdValid(id) {
    console.log(id)
    return this.list.filter((elem) => {
        return elem.id == id
    }).length > 0;
}
```

But this is taking over 4 seconds.

Comment: Are these ids unique per entry, or can there be id repetitions?

Comment: If you need to perform this check multiple times, then it might make more sense to extract the ids from the JSON first, and put them into a “normal” array ... so that you can then use built-in methods such as indexOf. You could then also try and see if ordering that array first brings any additional performance gain.

Comment: @FreemanLambda unique per entry

Comment: @CBroe I need to do this once per API hit if the requisite API is hit.

Comment: I would suggest a small conditional improvement. Instead of `Array.filter` use `Array.some`. Filter will go through the entire array no matter what, while Some might exit early if it finds a match.

Comment: while that tremendously improved performance for elements up in the JSON, it degraded performance for elements lower down the list @FreemanLambda

Comment: For a real solution then please use some sort of indexing, as proposed by @Sina Mansour in his answer. You can keep an up-to-date array of only sorted ids from your json and search there efficiently (i.e. binary).

Comment: @FreemanLambda funnily, If i keep only a list of ids in my JSON, filter takes 16 ms

Comment: Could be that the js compiler has no idea how to optimize a `{id: "1", name: "abc"}` object inside a loop, but perhaps it can easily optimize a simple literal value like `"1"`. Who knows :)

Comment: @AyushGupta start by removing `console.log(id)` from your code, and you will see a great drop on your numbers. Then, when you are searching for only one specific entry, go with `.find()` instead of `.filter()`. It would be good if could just make these changes and post the numbers for us to see.

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy Seriously? That took it down to 4ms. But how....

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy nvm, 600 ms for last element in the JSON

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy but i extracted all IDs from my JSOn from which i was loasding it to a seperate JSON and did an `indexOf` on the new JSON, `2ms`

Comment: @AyushGupta first, forget what I said about the `console.log()`. At first I thought it was happening inside the filter loop. The big improvement here is the use of `.find()` instead of `.filter()`. By design, `.find()` must be faster than `.filter()`, because it is meant to stop when finding the first occurrence that matches with the clause. But still, it is not the "Most efficient way". The last occurrence will still suffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to first sort the whole list (or insert it into a binary search tree) which takes some time but is only done once. and from there you can use binary search for the ID which is way faster.

here is a sample bst code for node:
[js-bst](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-bst)

also here is a package that can be used to query json data list very faster: [Defiant](http://defiantjs.com/)

### Edit

actually creating a hash table is a faster solution than a bst; here is a sample code that does the job:

```
data = [
    {
        "id":99,
        "name": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "id": 187,
        "name": "AXZ"
    }
]

var hashCache = {};
data.forEach(function(item){
    hashCache[item.id] = item.name
});

// Usage:
var id = '99';
var record = hashCache[id];
if (record) {
    alert(record);
} else {
    console.log('no match found');
}
```

you should also consider that this hash table only works if the IDs are unique. otherwise, you need to store a list of names in the hash table for each ID.

Comment: Why would this be faster than creating a hash?

Answer (score 0):

These are not the "Most efficient way to check". I'm posting here just as a reference about some ways to prepare the data to have a more performant search by a specific key.

Also is worth considering that in this script, `Map` can have a better performance, just because it is the last of all the executions. When its turn comes, V8 would have already been done some optimizations internally. So try to run each of them separately to have better findings.

```js
'use strict';

////////////////////////
// GENERATE TEST DATA //
////////////////////////
const dataSet = [];
let count = 213000;
while(count--) dataSet.push({id: count});
let idToBeFound = 212999;


// //////////////////////////
// // Using Literal Object //
// //////////////////////////
console.time('creatingIndexAsLiteralObject');
const literalObjectKeyedByID = dataSet.map(item => ({[item.id]: true}));
console.timeEnd('creatingIndexAsLiteralObject');

console.time('isIdValidSeekingOnLiteralObject');
console.log('isIdValidSeekingOnLiteralObject :: Found?', isIdValidSeekingOnLiteralObject(idToBeFound, literalObjectKeyedByID));
console.timeEnd('isIdValidSeekingOnLiteralObject');
function isIdValidSeekingOnLiteralObject(id, list) {
    return !!list[id];
}

// //////////////////////
// // Using Set Object //
// //////////////////////
console.time('creatingIndexAsSetObject');
const setObject = new Set(dataSet.map(item => item.id));
console.timeEnd('creatingIndexAsSetObject');

console.time('isIdValidSeekingOnSet');
console.log('isIdValidSeekingOnSet :: Found?', isIdValidSeekingOnSet(idToBeFound, setObject));
console.timeEnd('isIdValidSeekingOnSet');
function isIdValidSeekingOnSet(id, list) {
    return list.has(id);
}

//////////////////////
// Using Map Object //
//////////////////////
console.time('creatingIndexAsMapObject');
const mapObjectKeyedByID = new Map();
dataSet.forEach(item => mapObjectKeyedByID.set(item.id));
console.timeEnd('creatingIndexAsMapObject');

console.time('isIdValidSeekingOnMap');
console.log('isIdValidSeekingOnMap :: Found?', isIdValidSeekingOnMap(idToBeFound, mapObjectKeyedByID));
console.timeEnd('isIdValidSeekingOnMap');
function isIdValidSeekingOnMap(id, list) {
    return list.has(id);
}
```